# Getting cors error when using nextjs wth laravel 10

Tags: next.js, axios, laravel-10

I get cors error when I make axios get or post request in `Next.js` app

##### Error

[image]

##### CORS Configuration

Below is default `cors` configuration with `Laravel 10`

[image]

##### Api Routes

[image]